# NodeJS http get method access url in response function

Tags: node.js

I want to access http request url and parameters in callback function. When I print id with console.log I get error is id undefined. How can I access id and request url?

```
const Request = require('request');
var id=5;
Request.get('https://example.com/'+id, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log("id", id);
    }
});
```

Comment: In your code extract the id is undefined because you do not assign it. Either you should post the full code or if this is your full code, define the id first (e.g. `const id = 'my-id';`).

Comment: have you read [the documentation for this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#examples)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your code works .may be some syntax error issue,this is the updated
>   code. I tested it in my console and is working fine.

```
const Request = require('request');
var id=5;
Request.get('https://example.com/'+id, function (error, response, body) {

    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
console.log("id", id);

});
```

You might need to have a look at the official documentation of the Request package-[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#examples) and [link](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/10/consume-remote-api-data-nodejs-application/) which explains its usage in detail